# How to update TFS labelname by using VersionControlServer.CreateLabel() [C#][TFS]

Tags: c#, tfs

I´d like to update a label that was applied to a branch programmatically. While searching for a method that would do the trick, I found the VersionControlServer.CreateLabel()-Method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.createlabel(v=vs.120).aspx

I tried it like this, but it doesn´t seem to work:

```
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsuri));

    var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    string labelscope = "$/MyProjects/" + machinenumber;

    var specifiedBranch = vcs.QueryLabels(label, labelscope, null, true);

    string branch = specifiedBranch[0].Items[0].ServerItem;

    ItemSpec newItemSpec = new ItemSpec(branch, RecursionType.Full);

    string newItem = specifiedBranch[0].Items[0].ServerItem;

    newItemSpec.Item = newItem;

    VersionSpec versSpec = new LabelVersionSpec(label);

    LabelItemSpec newLabelItemSpec = new LabelItemSpec(newItemSpec, versSpec, false);

    LabelItemSpec[] newLabelItemSpecList = new LabelItemSpec[1] { newLabelItemSpec };

    string labelOwner = vcs.AuthenticatedUser;

    string labelName = label.Insert(6, "ed");

    VersionControlLabel labelToUpdate = new VersionControlLabel(vcs, labelName, labelOwner, branch, null);

    vcs.CreateLabel(labelToUpdate, newLabelItemSpecList, LabelChildOption.Replace);
```

What I exactly want to do is to update the old label name from "Deploy" to "Deployed". I know how to do this with TF.exe, but it should work without TF.exe.

Does anyone has an code example how to use the CreateLabel()-Methode for updateting a existing label?

**-- UPDATE --**

I changed

```
LabelItemSpec newLabelItemSpec = new LabelItemSpec(newItemSpec, versSpec, true);
```

to

```
LabelItemSpec newLabelItemSpec = new LabelItemSpec(newItemSpec, versSpec, false);
```

Now a new Label is created for the same branch. I cann delete the old label with VersionControlServer.DeleteLabel. Then I get the result that I was looking for, But I still would like to know how to update correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Renaming** Labels is not supported by TFS. You can only create a new Label based on the old Label you want to remove. Details please see this link: [Rename Label in Team Foundation Server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df3cbe0f-1c2e-4692-bc12-4a5a6c47c21a/rename-label-in-team-foundation-server?forum=tfsversioncontrol)

You could also verify this in [VersionControlLabel Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrollabel(v=vs.120).aspx).

> **Name**   Gets the name of this label.

It's only be able to get the name not set the name.

---

**Update**

For the **[LabelChildOption options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.labelchildoption(v=vs.120).aspx)**  in [VersionControlServer::CreateLabel Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138611(v=vs.120).aspx) , there are three options:

> - **Replace:** *Any item that you specify in your request that’s already in the label will be replaced by what you have specified.
>     Anything    that’s not in the label already will be added to  the
>     label, and    existing items that aren’t modified by your request will
>     remain as    they were.*
> - **Merge:** *Leave unmodified items that are in your request but that already exist in the label. Any item in your request that’s not
>
>     already in the label will be added to the label, and existing items
>
>     in the label that aren’t specified in your label will remain
>
>     unchanged.*
> - **Fail:** *Labels have the notion of a scope. The Fail option says that the call to create or update the label should fail if there is
>
>     at least one label by the same name that exists at a scope that would 
>     be below the scope of the new label.*

The update label only means update the **itemSpecs** parameter which means the item specs included in the label. So it's used to **update** the ItemSpec for the label – **Which Files, Folder we want to Label.**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read about that before and as I wrote before, I found a way to solve the problem by deleting the old label and setting a new one. So it´s okay for me. But what does "create or update" mean? As written here in the description line: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138611(v=vs.120).aspx. I would exepect that "update" means that I can update the labelname.